# How to use an HTML attribute to update an Angular variable

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding, dynamic-variables

I'm familiar with sharing this data in the opposite direction, i.e. using angular variables to update attributes,

e.g.

```
//js
$scope.itemVisible = false;
<--html-->
<div style="visibility:{{itemVisible}}">
```

and I'm also aware of the ability to update html via attribute with directives/components.

e.g.

```
//js
app.module('example', []).component('someComponent', {
    bindings: {
        someAttribute: '='
    },
    controller: function(){
        this.someValue = 'Schwifty'
    }
}

<--html-->   
<some-component some-attribute="someValue"></some-component>
```

But I'm wondering if there's a way to do this latter thing on plain html (not an original component/directive) like so...

e.g.

```
<--{{id}} being the value given to the id attribute in the container div -->

<div id="Snuffles"><span>{{id}}</span></div>
```

I know this isn't the right syntax, obviously, but this is me wishful thinking and giving a really bare-bones example of what I'd like to do.

Thanks!

Comment: So `{{id}}` should be updated with the `div.id='Snuffles'` ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: i want {{id}} to have the same value as the id in the div, yes. So it would render as "Snuffles"